# Unslider jQuery plugin not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, unslider

I'm trying to build up a slider in a personalized div inside a lighbox.

I use Lity for lightbox and Unslider for slides.

Unfortunately, the slider doesn't work properly, as overflow is set to "hidden" by the script (comes out it's inherited after element.style, as of Firebug).

If I force uncheck overflow for the slide element in developer tools in browser, it appears finally.

Here's the link to the actual site (click on an image):
http://foalenraged.com/david/index.php#inline7

The final version should be like this:

[image: Wanted result]

If there's a simple way to do the exact design with a better plugin, I'd be also greatful for the advice.

Thanks.